# Excel string match

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables with me

[image: IMG]

I need to compare "Column C" values in Table A, against "Column F" values in Table B and fill "Column D" with "Column G" values if a match is found.

For example "Column C" in Table A needs to be scanned for "Keells" (in Table B) and if a match is found adjacent cell in "Column D" needs to be filled with value "grocery" which is the adjacent value of "Keells".

Table B should be able to be populated with different entries too. If Column C has "phrases" that has no match against "column F" values they need to be filled as Other.

Answer (score 0):

In Cell D3 use the formula and drag it down.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(C3,(FIND(" ",C3,1)-1)),F2:G10,2,0),VLOOKUP(LEFT(C3,(FIND("-",C3,1)-1)),F2:G10,2,0))
```